# My new WordPress plugin version is not showing up in the plugin directory. It's been 4 days what could the problem be?

Tags: plugin-development, svn, repository

Hi to all
I made a wordpress plugin amtythumb post. All previous versions are reflected at worpress SVN within some hours. But this time 5.5 version of my plugin is not being reflected on wordpress plugin site even after 3-4 days.

just check wordpress plugin site wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amty-thumb-recent-post/
And SVN for confirmation, http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/amty-thumb-recent-post/amty-thumb-recent-post/tags/.

Please let me know what to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@articlestack

According to the [trac revision log](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/290503/amty-thumb-recent-post) you added a new directory under your root with the same name as the plugin.  It looks like your whole root directory got copied to the new directory because it contains all the tagged versions and trunk.  The plugin bot will not be able to find your newly tagged version unless it's in trunk or the new version is tagged in root/tags.

You can fix it by moving 5.5 back into the root tags dir.

`my-local-dir/$ svn cp amty-thumb-recent-post/trunk tags/5.5`

then delete the extra dir

`my-local-dir/$ svn del ampty-thumb-recent-post`

and check it back in

`my-local-dir/$ svn ci -m "tagging version 5.5"`

[image]

Comment: @articlestack thats not a silly mistake.  SVN can be confusing until get the hang of it.  I added all the details so it might help others who run into similar issues.  Since this worked for you please accept the answer so it will be added to our pool of answered questions.

Comment: I had done with all changes on root. But i dint delete amty-thumb-recent directory which i created inside. do i need to del it? because changes are still not reflected

Comment: The readme file says 5.5 but amtyThumb_posts.php says version 5.0 in both trunk and tags/5.5  check out trunk again from the svn then make sure everything is the right version then svn cp it over tags/5.5 then check it back in.